# Migrating cosmos Db using changeFeed in Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Below is the code I have written to migrate my one collection in another collection in same Cosmos database. I would like to know how can i optimize this and use "source" instead of creating client and collection uri and all.. I am sure there is a way to do it. I have to use change feed and interested in those documents which has "classID" as property.

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "databaseName",
            collectionName: "collectionName",
            StartFromBeginning = true,
            ConnectionStringSetting = "",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true
    )] IReadOnlyList<Document> source,    
    ILogger log )
        {
            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( "endpointUrl" ), "authorizationKey" );
            string continuationToken = null;
            string collectionUrl = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( "databaseName", "SourceCollection" ).ToString();
            do
            {
                var feed = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
                           collectionUrl,
                           new SqlQuerySpec( "select * FROM c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.ClassId)" ),
                           new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, RequestContinuation = continuationToken } ).AsDocumentQuery();
                var result = feed.ExecuteNextAsync().Result;
                var itemCount = result.Count;
                continuationToken = result.ResponseContinuation;
                foreach( var doc in result )
                {
                    var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( doc.ToString() );
                    string partitionkeyValue = string.Concat( data["ClassId"].Value<string>(), "|", data["Project"].Value<string>() );
                    data.Add( new JProperty( "PartitionKey", partitionkeyValue ) );
                    await client.CreateDocumentAsync( UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                   "SourceDatabase", "TargetCollection" ),
                   data );

                }
            }
            while( continuationToken != null );
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're asking how to get a reference to a client injected by the function? Two options to look at, one is to use dependency injection, another to get a client as input binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=csharp#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-documentclient

Comment: Depending on how many items you're migrating, you might want to be careful about using Azure Functions for this given the job time limits and underlying hardware. For a large migration probably better to run somewhere more durable like a VM.

Comment: I have around million records to be migrated. are you saying azure function is not feasible? I see running the sqlquery will get query the whole database at once . how can  enumerate that?

Comment: It depends on the plan. The consumption plan default is 5 minutes, so if your task tried to run longer than that, it would time out. See the advice "avoid long-running functions" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices

Comment: ok,isnt it like first time it runs and its start from beginning and in next trigger it picks up from where it left??

Comment: also I get comment on above code that it should be enumerated, since the query will run on whole database at once and that might cause issue. Can you help me how can i fix that?